# In C, how to remove all characters present in one array from another array?

Tags: c, character, c-strings

In C, how to remove all characters present in one array from another array?

Comment: Are you talking about `0` terminated strings? Is this homework?

Comment: what do you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like homework but here's a solution.

Make an array of 256 entries, like `char set[256]`.
Read the first string. For each character `c` set `set[(unsigned char)c]` to 1.
Read and copy the second string. For each character `c` if `set[c]` then skip `c`.

I forgot and left out that you must first `memset(set, 0, sizeof(set))` before setting any of its values to 1.

Comment: Why did you decide to pick 256? Also shouldn't that be an array of `int`s, not `char`s?

Comment: @Andrew: Standard 8-bit char. I suppose to be *really picky* you'd need to use preprocessor macros to determine the actual byte size.

Comment: @Andrew: I use char to save the space. It should actually be a bit vector but that's too much hassle and the macros are nasty.

Comment: 128 for ASCII should be sufficient in most all cases (not that it's that much space anyway).

Comment: @Andrew: Too risky. Any character over 127 would write on stack and would be a huge crash and security problem. 256 is guaranteed (as long as char is 8 bits) to be safe.

Comment: @Zan But but I thought the whole point of this website was to create stack overflows?!? I'm quite confused! `;)`

Comment: Also couldn't you do `char set[sizeof(char)*8]`?

Comment: @Andrew: No, that would result in 8. Much too small. sizeof(char) will *always* return 1, its size in bytes. However, C is free to redefine the size of a byte.

Comment: Oh whoops. I meant times 2^8 (and I don't mean bitwise XOR). Haha, `sizeof(byte)`? `;)` (note I'm not serious about the latter)

Comment: Make that `set[(unsigned char)c]`. `set[(unsigned)c]` is wrong because, if `char` is signed (which it usually is), it will be sign-extended, resulting in bogus indices for non-ASCII characters. The cast to unsigned has to be set before the `char` gets a chance to grow up.

Comment: The solution would still be `O(N+M)` if one pass is made to determine the maximum unsigned value in the filter string, which would be the size of the filter set.

Answer (score 2):

If they are numbers:

You can not "remove" them, but you can either set them to `0` (or any other value that can represent removal in your case) or create a new array which contains the numbers which do not belong in the subset of the two arrays.

The brute force way is to use two nested `for` loops

if they are `char`s:

you may "remove" them by "shifting"-"swapping"-"moving" all characters which do not belong in the common subset in the left, and then set the null terminator in the right place. (as long you do not mess with string literals (`char * p = "lala"`) this is fine). This will pretty much make the `char`s who are common to disappear.

Comment: They can be _removed_ if the arrays are for C strings.

Comment: @apalala, you mean with shifting ? You are correct. did not read the question full and I assumed they were numbers.

Comment: Is it possible to have some better way rather than using brute force (n*m times where n is the length of array 1 & m is the length of array 2)

Answer (score 2):

Assume you want to remove the chars in a0 that exist in a1.  First create a boolean array where each index is a character.  ex. x['c'] would be true if 'c' is found in a1.  Then loop through a0, checking the x array to see if a char should be kept or tossed.  You can create a new array with elements removed if needed.  This should be a O(n) operation.

Answer (score 1):

```
void remove_repeated(char* s, char* another)
{
    // ... preparation with another... see other answers
    for (pos = p = s; *p != 0; p++)
    {
        if (!macro_is_repeated(*p))
           *pos++ = *p;
    }
    *pos = 0;
}
```

See other answers for the `is_repeated` part.